# Custom section in Menu Umbraco7.6

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Can I add my custom menu item to this menu in admin Media page and how?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is is possible to add custom menu items to the various menus. Fort details on how to do this, see the documentations here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/extending/section-trees/trees-v7 at the bottom there is an example of adding a custom menu item. E.g.

```
//register the event listener:
TreeControllerBase.MenuRendering += TreeControllerBase_MenuRendering;

//the event listener method:
void TreeControllerBase_MenuRendering(TreeControllerBase sender, MenuRenderingEventArgs e)
{
    //this example will add a custom menu item for all admin users
    // for all content tree nodes
    if (sender.TreeAlias == "content"
        && sender.Security.CurrentUser.UserType.Alias == "admin")
    {
        e.Menu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("tweetLink", "Tweet this"));
    }
}
```